# Is there a limit on Docker Swarm overlay networks' bandwidth?

Tags: networking, docker, overlay, docker-swarm

I am running an eperiments which includes around 20 containers heavily communicating with each other through TCP, grpcs, etc. I use Docker stack command to start the containers on an overlay network. However, I have a feeling that there is a bottleneck in my network limiting the bandwidth as my containers are often not able to reach the others. When I monitor the Swarm, it seems that the containers don't use much of the network. so Is there a limit on Docker Swarm overlay networks' bandwidth?
[The grafana plots on network usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cU13.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a benchmarking held by Vadim Tkachenko ([original post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/03/testing-docker-multi-host-network-performance/)), docker overlay network has shown a very poor performance. Please check ksoftirq of your servers and if there's a high CPU load then using [Calico overlay plugin](https://github.com/projectcalico/calicoctl) is suggested.

Comment: Userful link: [Running Calico on a Docker Swarm](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/calico-docker/blob/master/docs/getting-started/powerstrip/CalicoSwarm.md)

Comment: Calico overlay plugin integration documentation with Docker Swarm is dated. I don't think that Calico still supports Docker Swarm.

Comment: @JanezKuhar ATM, my suggestion is either to use [Weave plugin for docker](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/install/plugin/plugin-v2/) or switch to Kubernetes to be able to use Calico. It depends on your use-case. However, as it's been a very long time since I posted this answer, I also suggest to run your own benchmark on Docker's overlay network vs Weave vs Calico to see if there have been any performance improvements.